# How do I achieve a Facebook Messenger/ Google Hangouts like layout to preview selected items in search bar on ANDROID?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, spannablestring, spannable

Basically what I want to create can be best illustrated from a screenshot.
[image: Screenshot preview]

I have a listview of people just like FB Messenger app. I want the ability for my users to have a search bar like the one shown in the screenshots.
It should have the following properties:

1) Search bar should preview names of people selected in the list view

2) People can be de-selected by hitting backspace on any name in the preview search bar

3) The search bar should be able to filter the bottom list of people as the user types.

I have a solution for propert 3) but I am clueless about the other two.
Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/RecipientsEditor.java).

This class uses combination of [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html), [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) and [Annotations](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html).

Comment: Can anyone give a working example project or library to achieve this.