# Custom Views in EditText, like in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: android, facebook, android-edittext, messaging

I am trying to implement a group-like thing in my app. So I was trying to create the "Create Group" view. It is really simple - Just 2 EditTexts and one button for confirmation. And a ListView showing the suggested users based on what you type.

But for the second EditText, I am trying to implement something like the one in Facebook Messenger and Hangouts: It is like an EditText but it has custom views in it (not just plain text) listing the users which you added.

I found someone who asked a similar question here: [How do I achieve a Facebook Messenger/ Google Hangouts like layout to preview selected items in search bar on ANDROID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006825/how-do-i-achieve-a-facebook-messenger-google-hangouts-like-layout-to-preview-se)

But I have no idea how to use the class in the answer.

Could anyone help? Thank you!