# Select item from list like facebook/hangouts friend selection android

Tags: android

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006825/how-do-i-achieve-a-facebook-messenger-google-hangouts-like-layout-to-preview-se), but the answer isn't sufficient for me to understand. Does anyone knows about any library or any good example by which I can achieve such kind of view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer : https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips

Comment: u bros saved my day :). Thanks a lot.